# Build Fails/Then passes in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, build, junit, netbeans-6.9

I have a Java Multiproject (About 15 sub projects) in Netbeans 6.9.1. Nearly all of these have JUNIT tests that should get run in the build cycle. I build locally prior to submitting an automated build to our servers. I've found that building locally I have a consistent issue:

1. If I build *with* tests (Just regular "Build"), it will fail. It used to fail with OOM PermSpace Exceptions until I increased the MaxPerm space. Now it fails while parsing a WSDL for one of the web services projects.
2. If I then do a "Build" again, directly following step 1, it will complete successfully with tests.
3. If I, instead of #1, Build and Skip Tests it will complete successfully the first time through.

At first glance this seems to be a resource issue or something when building the dependencies, or running the tests. However, the build in our build automation server works fine the first time and I have plenty of memory space allocated.

My peers have had the same issue, and continue to build twice. The workaround works, but I'm curious as to if any Netbeans veterans out there have any insight or similar experience?

Thoughts??

(EDIT:) More an more i think it could be configuration, here's whats in my default_options:

```
"netbeans_default_options-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-Xmx128m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-XX:MaxPermSize=200m ..."
```

Comment: There is an issue with String internalization in XML parsing: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-perfap1/index.html#strinter. Maybe strings are internalized in your case, and cost much perm space, a kind of memory leak.

Comment: Two questions: Have you tried building outside of NetBeans, i.e. using Ant? Have you tried using the latest version of NetBeans?

Comment: @Paul - Thanks for the response, indirectly yes. When I submit my job to our build servers it's built outside of Netbeans and runs fine the first time. Which is why I'm considering this is something internal to configuration or something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just left this on the table for a while, but for reasons other than the above I installed the latest Netbeans (7.1) and by default it looks like it has solved this problem. Or at least works better than 6.9. The following startup properties were supplied by default:

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -JDapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true"
```

This is far less beefy than before but seems to work. I've had a couple crashes but not near as bad as before. I may increase the memory limits slightly if it continues, but an upgrade seemed to solve the problem for the most part with far less resources.